# The correct way to refer using "their" in a sentence

Tags: possessive-pronouns

I need to choose a title for a paper and I'm unsure of the usage of **"their"**:

> Development of an orange juice for monkeys to enhance their jumping-capabilities in trees

Is **"their"** in this context referring correctly to the monkeys or is it grammatically wrong, because **"Development of an orange juice for monkeys"** is the construct that **"their"** would refer to?

Do I need to use something like this instead?:

> Development of an orange juice for monkeys to enhance the monkeys' jumping-capabilities in trees

#### UPDATE

Maybe its would be better to compare constructs that are more related to **things** than to **beings** because it is more closely related to my actual use case (I don't know if that would even make a difference):

> Development of a language for protocols to enhance their applicability in automatic communication

Is **"their"** in this case still referring grammatically correct to **"protocols"**?

Comment: I would understand _their_ as referring to the monkeys.

Comment: (Following your edit) Yes, because _protocols_ is plural.

Comment: Ok, so any ambiguity is resolved by the fact that "their" is plural and so fits only to "protocols" resp. "monkeys" - so the rule for what "their" refers to, is actual that it refers to whatever fits best (within the restrictions of grammatically correctness)?

Comment: I think so, yes.